# With a DevExpress Master-Detail grid, how do I bind to the SelectedItem in a child grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, master-detail, devexpress-wpf

*Note: This entry is of the type "Share your knowledge, Q&A Style". I answer my own question, below.*

Unfortunately, in a DevExpress grid with Master-Detail, `SelectedItem` does not work on the child grid.

How can I work out which item is selected in the child grid?

Answer (score 1):

[This has been superseded](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4402):-

> Please note that this approach is **outdated** starting with version 15.1, where the capability to bind selection of the master and detail grids was supported out of the box. Starting with that version, bind the CurrentItem/SelectedItem/SelectedItems properties directly as described at [Master-detail grid - Add the capability to bind selection and navigation properties](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T106654).
>
> > *The following properties of the master-detail grid now support binding: **`SelectedItem`, `CurrentItem`, `SelectedItems`**. Specify the `DataControlDetailDescriptor.ParentPath` property or handle the `DataControlDetailDescriptor.CustomGetParent` event to enable the binding from the ViewModel to the grid.*

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This entry is of the type "Share your knowledge, Q&A Style". I answer my my own question, above.*

After struggling with this for a while, I found that the best way to solve this is to create your own attached property, as per these instructions:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4402

Here is some sample code that shows how it works. The approach depends on the version of the DevExpress library, as per the link above.

```
<grid:GridControl x:Name="BasketSearchBasketGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Baskets}" ToolTip="Double click to show details.">
    <grid:GridControl.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding Path=SelectRowCmd}"/>
    </grid:GridControl.InputBindings>
    <grid:GridControl.View>
        <grid:TableView x:Name="view" AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" AutoWidth="True" NewItemRowPosition="None"
                            DetailHeaderContent="Search Results"
                            NavigationStyle="Row"
                            ShowFixedTotalSummary="False"
                            ShowGroupPanel="True"
                            ShowGroupedColumns="True"
                            ShowAutoFilterRow="false"
                            FadeSelectionOnLostFocus="False"
                            ShowIndicator="False"
                            BestFitMode="AllRows">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <!-- We could use SelectedRow, however, to keep things consistent with the way child rows work, use this
                instead. -->
                <devExpressBehaviour:MasterFocusedRowBehavior FocusedRow="{Binding SelectedBasket, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </grid:TableView>
    </grid:GridControl.View>
    <grid:GridControl.Columns>
        <grid:GridColumn Header="Basket Name" FieldName="BasketName" MinWidth="60"/>
        <grid:GridColumn Header="BasketStyle" FieldName="BasketStyle" MinWidth="40"/>
    </grid:GridControl.Columns>
    <grid:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
        <dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor ItemsSourcePath="Orders" ShowHeader="False">
            <grid:GridControl x:Name="BasketSearchOrderGrid" Tag="orderDetails"                                                      
                    >
                    <grid:GridControl.Columns>
                        <grid:GridColumn Header="Side" FieldName="Side" MinWidth="20"/>
                        <!-- More columns here -->
                    </grid:GridControl.Columns>
                    <grid:GridControl.View>
                    <dxg:TableView ShowGroupPanel="False">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <!-- DevExpress does not support SelectedRow on a child grid. Use this custom behavior instead. -->
                            <devExpressBehaviour:DetailFocusedRowBehavior FocusedRow="{Binding SelectedOrder, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </dxg:TableView>
                </grid:GridControl.View>
                </grid:GridControl>
        </dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor>
    </grid:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
</grid:GridControl>
```

The key is these lines, within the `<TableView>` tab of the child grid. These effectively replace the non-working method of keeping track of the selected item (i.e. `SelectedItem`) with an attached property that actually works.

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <!-- DevExpress does not support SelectedRow on a child grid. Use this custom behavior instead. -->
    <devExpressBehaviour:DetailFocusedRowBehavior FocusedRow="{Binding SelectedOrder, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Please DevExpress, make it easy on us, this should just work!